# How to configure /etc/network/interface to use static IPv6, but dynamic IPv4?

Tags: networking, services, dhcp, ipv6, static-ip

I want to add a static IPv6 IP to my otherwise automatic IP configuration.
How to do this?

Currently I use:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
```

So IPv4 is configured by DHCP, IPv6 is configured by rtadv.
However, I want to have additionally an IPv6 static adress? How to do this?

I tried with

```
iface eth0 inet6
address 2001:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::3/64
netmask 64
gateway 2001:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::1
```

But this results in a failure? (init-Script not terminates with code 100)

Comment: Why not use `NetworkManager`, wich should be used since 12.04(?) instead of the `*config` family. See `man NetworkManager`

Answer (score 9):

Test this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet6 static
address 2001:db8::xxxx:yyyy
netmask 64
gateway 2001:db8::xxxx:yy:zzzz
```